# Deny Access to generated PDFs ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, restrict

I am trying to deny access to pdf files so that a person can not access soemthing like

www.abcd.cm/pdf/UserName.pdf

I already have my pdf folder's access denied with

```
<location path="~/pdf">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

It does not block access to the files inside, just the folder itself.

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest avoiding calling your PDFs the users username, rather use a random string and associate it with your user in a database somewhere. The first answer fixes your issue, however you don't want a directory of easily identifiable content that anyone could stumble upon.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution to my problem, but the option might no be available to me at this time; I will have to check,

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do a check in the `Application_BeginRequest` event of the `Global.asax` file:

E.g:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToUpper

    If path.EndsWith(".PDF") Then
        Response.Redirect("/Disallowed.aspx", True)
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This hasn't seemed to solve my issue, I can still directly access the pdf